# How can i add a condition to fire my trigger when my opp stagename is closed?

Tags: trigger

How can i add a condition to fire my trigger when my opp stagename is closed?

```
trigger TriggerOnPrevious on Opportunity (before update) {
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
        String oldStageName = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName;
        if(opp.StageName != oldStageName){
             opp.Previous_stage__c = oldStageName;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask], as it will help you write questions in a way that will help the community help you.

Answer (score 1):

Update your if condition with below code

`if( opp.StageName.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed Won') && opp.StageName != oldStageName)`

Comment: apex is case inSenSitIvE, so equalIgnorecase and == will give the same result.